# How to find a CDF of Y(X) given that we know a probability distribution of X?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Suppose we know probability distribution of X. For simplicity let's say `X~UniformDistribution[]`. There is also a defined function Y of X (e.g. Y=1/X). How to find a probability distribution for Y?

Answer (score 5):

Use [`TransformedDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedDistribution.html)

```
distY = TransformedDistribution[1/x,
   x \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[]];
```

The [`PDF`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PDF.html) is then

```
PDF[distY, y]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** corrected error in syntax

```
CDF[distY, y]
```

[image]

```
Plot[{CDF[distY, y], PDF[distY, y]}, {y, 1, 5},
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {0.7, 0.4}]]
```

[image]

Comment: The command CDF[TransformedDistribution[1/X, 
   X \ [Distributed] UniformDistribution[{a, b}]], t] // Simplify handles the general case.

Comment: @corey979: I think the correct syntax is CDF[distY, y] which works well, not CDF[distY[y]].

Comment: @user64494 - Thanks, I corrected my error.